I am getting this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Provided camera selector unable to resolve a camera for the given use case
I am attaching the code below. I am inverting an camera on click of a button starting the camera on view created of an fragment and click image on click of a button.
//used for inverting the camera.
private fun invertCamera() {
        cameraSelector = if (cameraSelector == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA) {
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
        } else {
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
        }
        //start the camera again..
        startCamera()
    }

private fun startCamera() {

        val processCameraProvider =
            ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireActivity().applicationContext)

        val aspectRatioStrategy = AspectRatioStrategy.RATIO_4_3_FALLBACK_AUTO_STRATEGY

        processCameraProvider.addListener({
            try {
                cameraProvider = processCameraProvider.get()
                imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                    .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                    .setResolutionSelector(ResolutionSelector.Builder()
                        .setResolutionStrategy(ResolutionStrategy( Size(800,600),
                            ResolutionStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_CLOSEST_LOWER_THEN_HIGHER))
                        .setAspectRatioStrategy(aspectRatioStrategy).build())
                    .build()
                val previewUseCase =
                    Preview.Builder().build()
                previewUseCase.setSurfaceProvider(binding.cameraView.surfaceProvider)
                cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, previewUseCase)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d("Sunny", "Error$e")
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireActivity().applicationContext))

        if (imagePath != "" && firstTimePhoto){
            firstTimePhoto = false
            binding.imagePreview.isVisible = true
            binding.captureImage.text = "Upload"
            Picasso.get().load(FILE_UPLOAD +imagePath).into(binding.imagePreview)
            binding.captureAgain.isVisible = true
        }
    }

private fun captureImage() {

        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageCapture)

        imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireActivity().applicationContext),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                @ExperimentalGetImage
                override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                    super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
                    //get bitmap from image and handle rotation...
                    val capturedImageBitmap =
                        image.image?.toBitmap()?.rotate(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat())

                    //unbind camera ....
                    cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
                    binding.imagePreview.isVisible = true

                    //rotation handled...
                    binding.imagePreview.setImageBitmap(capturedImageBitmap?.let { flip(it) })
                    //validate from python api...
                    if (capturedImageBitmap != null) {
                        validateUserImage(capturedImageBitmap)
                    }
                    image.close()
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    super.onError(exception)
                    Log.d("Sunny", "$exception")
                }
            })
    }



I am unable to understand why this error occurs as I am unable to replicate it. It exits of various devices according to firebase crashlytics.

What is the CameraX version and is there a stacktrace for the exception? (e.g. is the exception thrown in case of Preview being bound or ImageCapture? also in case of which camera selector?)

def camerax_version = "1.3.0-rc01" , private var cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMER , I am not sure where is the exception is being thrown in case of Preview or ImageCapture as I am using macbook pro m2 and the firebase is not telling me which line the error is on as I used to do previously. @TahsinMasrur

Does it tell which devices have this problem? Maybe the device actually doesn't have a front camera?
If you aren't already using it, consider using the (ProcessCameraProvider#hasCamera(CameraSelector))[https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/lifecycle/ProcessCameraProvider#hasCamera(androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector)] API first to ensure the camera does exist for devices which may not have a camera of a specific lens.

It's also possible that some devices have camera hardware issues and the camera is not always unavailable. It seems likeCameraX has enhanced their retry mechanism in 1.4.0 and added more control/customization for this which might help in such case. See their RetryPolicy documentation for details.

Thanks for the info @TahsinMasrur, Yes it says which devices are facing the issue like Redmi 10, etc. I have checked devices have both the front and back camera, yes it can be hardware issue has I have seen same problems on stackoverflow due to hardware issues.
